# Get value by property from javascript object list

Tags: javascript

i want to get property value from javascript object list, i have a list

```
var cars = [{ id: 1, name: 'Audi' }, { id: 2, name: 'BMW' }, { id: 1, name: 'Honda' }];
```

Now i want get id or name property value by using for loop like this

```
var cars = [{ id: 1, name: 'Audi' }, { id: 2, name: 'BMW' }, { id: 1, name: 'Honda' }];
 var items=[];
 var firstProp='id';
 for (var i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {

  //original work
  items.push({ value: model[i].firstProp});//here is the problem
 }
```

please give good advise, thanks.

Comment: hi, @cookiemonster, no duplicate here.

Comment: What do you mean "no duplicate here"? It's exactly what you need. Same question. Same issue. Same answer.

Comment: ...or if you're not happy with that duplicate,  you'll find many others if you [use Google](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&q=javascript+get+object+property+using+variable+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=javascript+get+object+property+using+variable+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: ...notice also that the solution is even in your question. `model[i]` is using a variable to access the property of an object. And yes, I know it's an Array. Arrays are Objects in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you should use square bracket notation instead of dot notation:

```
//..  
items.push({ value: model[i][firstProp]});//here is the problem
```

Comment: Yes you are correct from what I see from the OP's post `model[i].firstProp` is calling the property `firstProp` and not `id` as assigned to that variable though it would just be easier to use `model[i].id`

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this

```
items.push({ value: model[i][firstProp]});
```

the `.` notation expects the `firstProp` to be present as a key in dictionary, since the `firstProp` is a variable that contains a string you should use `[]` notation.